# Prove that the composition of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Let $X,Y,Z$ be subsets of $\textbf{R}$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function which is uniformly continuous on $X$, and let $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be a function which is uniformly continuous on $Y$. Show that the function $g\circ f:X\rightarrow Z$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since both $g$ is uniformly continuous, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta_{1} > 0$ such that for every $w,z\in Y$ we have that
\begin{align*}
|w - z| \leq \delta_{1} \Longrightarrow |g(w) - g(z)| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}
On the other hand, $f$ is uniformly continuous too. Then for every $\delta_{1} > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x,y\in X$ we have that
\begin{align*}
|x - y| \leq \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| \leq \delta_{1}
\end{align*}

Hence, if we make the substitution $w = f(x)$ and $z = f(y)$, we conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
|x - y| \leq \delta \Longrightarrow |g(f(x)) - g(f(y))| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}
thence we conclude that $g\circ f$ is uniformly continuous as well.

Could someone provide any comments on the proposed solutions?

Comment: If function maps cauchy sequence to cauchy sequence [doesn't](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27901/does-cauchy-continuity-imply-uniform-continuity-no) imply function is uniformly continuous

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequence onto Cauchy sequences, but the converse in not true in general. Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just phrase it a bit differently.

Say $\delta_g$ and $\varepsilon_g$ in the first line, and $\delta_f$ and $\varepsilon_f$ in the second.

Then you only need to consider $\varepsilon_f\leq \delta_g$ and take, as you say, $w=f(x),z=f(y)$ to conclude.

I'm just pointing out the fact that the $\epsilon_f$ has to meet some requirements in order for $g$ to do as you desire. You can't say "for every $\delta$" everywhere because it's not really true. They are related.